# Rails 4: Limit URL's to the main domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, subdomain

Something I've noticed using subdomains with Rails is, that every controller action, which is not specifically assigned to a subdomain can get accessed via every subdomain.
**For example:**

```
get "/hello" => "welcome#hello"
```

is not just available through "domain/hello" but also through "subdomain.domain/hello"
Can I limit this controller action to just be accessible for "domain/hello"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get "hello", to: "welcome#hello", constraints: { subdomain: "" }
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: Try an empty string with subdomain